# mprotect returns ENOMEM for address space in solib, any workarounds?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I am trying to get write access to particular address space in shared library that is dynamically loaded, with dlopen call. is there any restriction in doing this ? I know it can be done because solibs can be debugged using gdb. Gdb uses mprotect to get write access to solibs to insert and clear breakpoints.

As return I get -1 as return and 29 as error number, perror gives `ENOMEM Cannot allocate memory`

```
ENOMEM  
The application has requested Single UNIX Specification, Version 2 compliant behavior, but addresses in the range are not valid for the address space of the process, or the addresses specify one or more pages that are not attached to the user's address space by a previous mmap or shmat subroutine call.
```